# Which data type should I use?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a set of data, lets call them shapes.

There are 3 types of shapes:

```
1) circle :
x-coordinate
y-coordinate
r-radius
c-color

2) square:
x-coordinate
y-coordinate
s-side
c- color

3) line:
x-coordinate
y-coordinate
x1-coordinate
y1-coordinate
c- color
```

Which **data type is best suited** for them? Should I make a shape class and make the circle, square and line as subclasses of shape? If I do, can I put all of them in one class file?

As a side note:
When creating each shape, constructor will be given only maxX and maxY. The shaped will be autogenerated with random numbers which will stay inbound within (0,0,maxX,maxY). Their sizes are also user-determined. I am keeping them from 1/10 to 1/3 or the width of screen. But they are less-important details.

Comment: Your approach looks ok. Why do you doubt about it?

Comment: Silent downvotes are of no use.

Comment: its a real shame people discouraging new comers without even commenting or leaving a feedback

Comment: I feel like I am going with "what feels right" instead of "good java-programming practice" or convention. If there is one I wanna follow them.

Answer (score 5):

You could have a super class called `Shape`, which would have all the common properties (`x-coordinate`, `y-coordinate` and `colour`).

You would then extend this class with your `Circle`, `Square` and `Line` classes, wherein you fill in the extra properties that each distinct item has. *It is recommended that you have a separate class file for each class.*

This approach would allow you to, for instance, create a `List<Shape>` should you need to create a collection of shapes.

Comment: And allows him to easily add a new type of Shape without much hassle.

Comment: Thanks, that's the affirmation that I really needed. Is it possible to do implement the super class and subclasses in a single file tho?

Comment: @theMobDog: You could declare them if you declare the classes as private, but I would not recommend it. If you want to declare your classes as `public`, you will need to have them in a separate file.

Comment: Yeah. I wanted them as public. So I ended up making a shape class with String type that specify the type of the shape. Even tho all shapes have the same 4 integers. Some will be unused and some will be different. For example 3rd integer would be a radius for circle and side for square.

Comment: @theMobDog: I would not recommend you use this approach. If you want to denote different shapes, it might be best to use different classes. This could provide an unclear context for the fields used.

Comment: That made sense. I was unsure about the whole thing. Wasn't specified to use subclass so I was trying to avoid it. But yeah my approach was pretty shaky.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

An alternative representation is by giving the bounding box `(X0, Y0, X1, Y1)` or `(X, Y, W, H)`, whatever the shape type.

For line segments, there can be a swap (`Y0 <=> Y1`) unfortunately. It may be worth to distinguish upline and downline (internally).

For circles and squares, you'll have to enforce the constraint `X1-X0=Y1-Y0` or `W=H`.

This scheme is also convenient for axis-aligned rectangles and ellipses.

Whether you use a single class with a type field or virtualization is mostly a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

In Java more or less everything is a class. It's not different in other datastructures you probably use, like a basic Set and more fine granular types like Treeset and Hashset. All of them are classes.

In your case you probably want an abstract class or interface to implement the general Shape. Circles, Squares, Lines would be implemented as "normal" classes which inherit from Shape.

It is a convention to use one source code file per class. Especially when the source code gets bigger and you write a lot of different methods for the different shapes this is much more readable.

But I don't get why you give your constructor the max values. Don't forget: A constructor creates **one** object, so you schould give it only the actual values for x and y and calculate those outside of your class.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer about the classes and constructor. I could never figure out "the best practice" and always going with what feels right

Answer (score 0):

Use Long for the numbers. As double and  float cant be used if you need precise values.

Answer (score 0):

Let me first state that this is not the best solution but I ended up using factory methods for different shapes. Since we only have 3 shapes and being a relatively small program. Making a class for each one, seems like killing an ant with a sledgehammer.

I learnt a lot from all the different answers and opinions. You guys rocks and keep rocking on!

Thanks,
theMobDog